# Showing me BSMachError

Tags: ios, swift

Showing me error after showing notification object in Textbox.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("Search")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Modify(_:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)
}

func Modify(_ notification: Notification){
    print(notification.object as Any)
    txtSearch.text = notification.object as? String // showing Error after executing this line
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the exact error?

Comment: when you post notification what you have passed ?